# E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

This code is the mainactivitv.java class which is used to display the data from database which is present in the server

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetAllDevices extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/db_connect.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "data_9297";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "coldstorage_id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "device_id";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_TIME = "time";
    private static final String TAG_TEMP = "temp";
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Dashboard.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetAllDevices.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "POST", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Threshold.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            GetAllDevices.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

This is JSONParser.java class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

This is what the logcat shows

```
03-23 13:11:20.140 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
03-23 13:11:20.141 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x45
03-23 13:11:20.141 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x44
03-23 13:11:20.146 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-23 13:11:20.149 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x57
03-23 13:11:20.155 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414bd9a8)
03-23 13:11:20.156 2282-2959/com.gopal.coldstorage D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x1D
03-23 13:11:20.167 2282-2282/com.gopal.coldstorage D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-23 13:11:20.196 2282-2951/com.gopal.coldstorage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at com.gopal.coldstorage.GetAllDevices$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetAllDevices.java:132)
                                                                         at com.gopal.coldstorage.GetAllDevices$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetAllDevices.java:107)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

This is db_connect.php file

```
<?php
$response = array();



$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "received_data");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM data_9297 ORDER by coldstorage_id ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 // looping through all results

    // products node

   $response["data_9297"] = array();


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
        // temp user array

      $data = array();


/* numeric array */
$data["coldstorage_id"]= $row[0] ;
$data["device_id"]= $row[1] ;
$data["date"]= $row[2]; 
$data["time"]= $row[3] ;
$data["temp"]= $row[4] ;
array_push($response["data_9297"], $data);
}
 $response["success"] = 1;


   // echoing JSON response

  echo json_encode($response);

} 
else {

  // no products found

$response["success"] = 0;

  $response["message"] = "No devices found";


  // echo no users JSON

 echo json_encode($response);

}



/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: At which line you'r getting error?

Comment: Can you specify line number 132 and 107 in your task??

Comment: Looks like the line 132 is this one **Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());**, so json is null. There are many printStacktrace that should be Log.e(...). Look at your JSONParser class, the problem must be there.

Comment: **json = sb.toString();** is your problem my friend, remove it! It has not been instantiated, that's what it crashes

Comment: I don't think so, **json** is initialized and **StringBuilder** is initialized too. What is null is the **JSONObject** return from JSONParser.

Comment: 132 is Log.d("All Products:",json.toString());

Comment: 107 is the class name LoadAllProducts

Comment: What should I do so that JSONObject does not return null???

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are getting crash at

```
Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
```

seems json object is null.